# Notification BigPictureStyle passes old Intent Extras

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

When a normal notIfication builder is created, extra values are passed correctly. But when i downaload an image and add the image as BigPictureStyle to the notification, it passes old Intent Extras.

Comment: provide some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was prompting the download after declaring the Notification Builder. Download the image before initializing the notification builder.